# How find the most decisive sentences or words in a document via Doc2Vec?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I've trained a Doc2Vec model in order to do a simple binary classification task, but I would also love to see which words or sentences weigh more in terms of contributing to the meaning of a given text. So far I had no luck finding anything relevant or helpful. Any ideas how could I implement this feature? Should I switch from Doc2Vec to more conventional methods like tf-idf?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with SO, try [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about model interpretability. Some ways I have seen this explored:

- Depending on your classifier, the parameters of the model may tell you what it is looking at. For example, in attention-based models, what the model attends to is telling.
- Tools like [Lime](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) and [Anchor](https://github.com/marcotcr/anchor) are useful for any black box model, and will probably work in this case. The documentation for both shows how to use it with text data.